# Cartesian Product without Itertools Infinite loop

Tags: python, cartesian-product

*First of all, I study math, so I'm sorry if my code and terminologies are all over the place and unstructured at all.*

I need to write a code that takes in n amounts of variables as an input (variadic) and list down all of  the possible 'organized' cartesian product.

'Organized' here means, if there are n elements (in this case maybe lists or straight up int/str), I need the result to be in order of ( element from input[0], element from input[1],..., element from input[n] )
example:

input : [ ['a','b'] , ['c','d','e'] ]

output : [ ('a','d'),('a','e'),...]

I'm aware I can just use itertools, but that's not the point of the excercise. My current attempt to do it is :

- My input here is:

```
    x = [['a','b','c'],['d','e']]
```

- Generate a base case for later iteration, x here is already a list of inputs ( the parent function will be def func(*x) ). I'm taking the first element on the input and list down all possible combinations from that single input (in this case all the elements itself)

```
    def initiate(x):
        t = []
        for i in x[0]:
            t.append([i])
        return t
```

```
a = initiate(x)
```

a = [['a'],['b'],['c']]

- Remove the first element of x, since we already made all possible combinations with it

```
    def cont(x):
        r = x[:]
        r.pop(0)
        return r
```

```
b = cont(x)
```

b = [['d','e']]

- Next, I want to make all possible combinations of a and b. My idea is take all elements of a, append each of the 'old' elements with the *first element of the first element of b*,append these 'new' elements into a list, then proceed with the *second element of the first element of b*, and so on. Here is my attempt:

```
    def proceed(b,a):
        result = []
        for i in b[0]:
            t = []
            s = a[:]
            for old in s:
                s.append(i)
            for new is s:
                t.append(new)
            for ele in t:
        result.append(ele)
        return result
```

I was hoping it will do something like this:

```
a = [['a'],['b'],['c']]
b = [['d','e']]
t = []
t = [['a','d'],['b','d'],['c','d']]
result = [['a','d'],['b','d'],['c','d']]
t = []
t = [['a','e'],['b','e'],['c','e']]
result = t = [['a','d'],['b','d'],['c','d'],['a','e'],['b','e'],['c','e']]
```

However this results in an infinite loop. I would like to know why, and whether or not this is a retarded approach, and how to do it in a better way. Thank you

Comment: What's the smallest test case which doesn't work? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: After reading the link u sent, I'm still not 100% sure what it means, but its with the 'proceed' function, and inputs: { a = [['a'],['b'],['c']] }, {b = [['d','e']]} . proceed(b,a) creates an infinite loop

Comment: You are looping over `s` and appending to `s` so it will loop forever (until you run out of memory)